# Trying to copy the remainder of a string after a character

Tags: c, string, c-strings, strcpy, strchr

I am trying to copy the remainder of a user inputted string. It is always input in the following: airport, 00:00, 00:00. The numbers are flight times and layover times. In my code I've gotten it to spit out the airport, but trying to use strchr to find everything after the 1st "," is a pain. Is there a way I can remove the airport and put the rest into a new string and continue to use strchr? I have to reformat the strings separated by commas is the goal. The end result should be “city has flight time tt.tt hoursand layover time tt.tt hours”. I cannot use scanf or the like so it looks like strchr and strcopy might be my only options. Any help is appreciated.

What I have currently gives me an error when trying to find the char after the last "," in the string.

Assignment Rules: Do not use strtok(), any scanf-related functions, any functions that do tokenization of string data.

```
int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    int flightTimeNum = 0;
    char userInput[81] ="";
    char userInputNew[81] = "";
    char cityNew[20] = "";
    char flightTime[20] = "";
    char layOverTime[20] = "";


    fgets(userInput, 81, stdin);
    char *city;
    char *flight;
    char *layover;

    city = strchr(userInput, ',');
    strncpy(cityNew, userInput, city - userInput);
    printf("%s\n" ,cityNew);

    layover = strrchr(userInput, ',');
    strncpy(layOverTime, userInput, layover - userInput);
    printf("%s\n", layOverTime);

    printf("Press ENTER key to Continue\n");
    getchar();

}
```

Comment: Have you looked at strtok?

Comment: Sorry ill update my post, the rules are "Do not use strtok(), any scanf-related functions, any functions that do tokenization of string data"

Comment: I've been basically pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to do it when strchr seems to only like for one instance of a specific character, so any help might just save my sanity!

Comment: Since this is an assignment I'm not going to post an answer, but here is a hint. 
 `strncpy(flightTime, userInput, flightTime - userInputNew);`  --> This doesn't look right at all.  `flightTime` and `userInputNew` do not point to the same array.  That subtraction will not give you what you want.  You probably want to base your arithmetic off `city` and `flight`.  But you should also check your assumptions that `city` > `flight` and that neither are NULL.

Comment: you also want to make sure you null terminate your strings

Comment: I have updated my code, and they both work to spit out the destination, and the layover time, although my layover math spits out everything since it doesnt know I want the city removed as well, any way around this?

Comment: *Do not use (...) any functions that do tokenization of string data* meaning "but you can write your own"?

Comment: is the word 'airport' actually the name of a city, or is it the actual word airport?

Comment: If it is a city, then it seems like you should search for the first occurence of a digit.

Comment: I have updated my answer to look for a digit rather than for airport -- guessing that airport is really a replacement for any of a number of cities.  Is that closer to what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `strchr` you could consider creating substrings by replacing each ',' with a null terminator `\0` and then setup the pointers to each sub string based on the length of the previous string.

Alternatively, you could can through the string accumulating the characters until you reach a `,` and then terminate the buffer and start accumulating the next part of the string into the next buffer, and repeat until you reach the null terminator of the `userInput`.

Example of the first approach, note you should validate that you were able to create the expected number of substrings etc. just in case the user enters invalid data.

```
// NULL terminate each substring
char *p = userInput;    // Point to the beginning of the string
for(;;) {
    p = strchr(p, ','); // Find first ',' starting from 'p'
    if (!p) break;      // If not found break out of loop
    *p = '\0';          // otherwise replace ',' with a null terminator
    ++p;                // move pointer 'p' to the next character
}

// Setup pointers to each substring
city = userInput; 
flight = city + strlen(city) + 1;
layover = flight + strlen(flight) + 1;
```

Comment: Replacing characters by nuls is what I usually do (and what `strtok()` does internally), as it allows you to use `strlen()` and others. But note that it will fail on `const char*`, when the memory is *really* read-only (e.g. stored in ROM).

Comment: @Matthieu, good point however the example does show this coming in as user input so that would not apply in this particular case.

Comment: Yes, it usually isn't a problem (even `const char*` can be cast to `char*`...). I just wanted to raise that point because it happened to me in my sxmlc parser: people use it in embedded OS where such things happen (configuration file stored in PROM) and writing to it causes a core dump...

Comment: `*p++ = 0;` sorry ;)

Comment: @Matthieu, no need to be sorry help is always appreciated (at least it should be). Since the OP is clearly learning, right or wrong, I chose to separate each step so that I could comment it and hopefully make it clear what was going on.

Comment: This was probably the most clear in terms of where you are headed, once I have set the pointers below, can I reference the pointer to arrays to print out the data after?

Comment: Im confused as to what I need to do with the pointers below the loop to have them in printable, separate string arrays.

Comment: That is correct, each pointer will point to a separate string (each substring of the original string). `printf("%s", city)` will print the city, `printf("%s-%s", city, flight)` with print the city and the flight.

Comment: Okay got it to print, good lord this is confusing, now if I wanted to actually take the "00:00" and reformat to 00.00, could I reuse the loop above to replace the ":" with a "." with some changes?

Comment: Nevermind I got it to work! Quick question, in the loop you have "for (;;)" is the ";;" just a place holder or what exactly is that saying?

Comment: `for(;;)` is a way to create an infinite loop, which is why we need to break out of the loop when we no longer find commas in the input string.

Comment: As for replacing the `:` with `.`, you can do the following `while (*p) if (*p == ':') *p = '.';` This assumes that `p` is pointing to the start of the string, so if you want to change the `:` in the `layout` string you can have `char *p = layout;` and then run the while loop to do the replacement. You might consider putting that into a function that you can call for each string you want to do the change for.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, the info you gave was enough to throw me into the right direction, and actually grasp the strchr function!

Answer (score 2):

While you are free to parse the information from each line with a pointer and `strchr` (or by simply walking a pointer down your buffer), when dealing with *formatted input*, using a *formatted input function* like `sscanf` can greatly help.

Let's take a look at both. In your question you want to read with `fgets` (good), and then find the first comma, and then copy the remainder of the line to a new buffer. All good so far. The only caveat is once you locate the first comma, you still must advance the pointer from the comma, skipping any whitespace, until you reach the first character for the remainder of the times (rest of the line).

A simple approach that simply outputs the remainder of the string following the first comma omitting any intervening whitespace could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXC 1024   /* if you need a constant, define one (or more) */

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC];

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {      /* read with fgets */
        char *p;
        buf[strcspn (buf, "\r\n")] = 0;     /* trim '\n' from end */
        if ((p = strchr (buf, ','))) {      /* find 1st ',' */
            do
                p++;                    /* advance pointer */
            while (*p && isspace (*p)); /* to end or 1st non-whitespace */
        }
        printf ("rest of string: '%s'\n", p);   /* output rest of line */
    }
}
```

(**note:** when declaring constants, don't *Skimp* on buffer size.)

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/airport_times.txt
KOCH, 01:01, 01:51
KAXX, 03:50, 05:40
KADS, 07:40, 09:30
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/airport_gettimes <dat/airport_times.txt
rest of string: '01:01, 01:51'
rest of string: '03:50, 05:40'
rest of string: '07:40, 09:30'
```

Now let's look at using `fgets` for the read and the formatted-input function `sscanf` to parse all needed values from each line. (or you could use `fscanf` to do it in one call, but you are better off using `fgets` and then `sscanf` to (1) ensure you consume an entire line of data and (2) can independently validate the read and parse of values.

The approach is similar, read with `fgets`, but then instead of looking for the first comma with `strchr`, simply use `sscanf` to read the ICAO, Arrival time and Departure Time into separate buffers in one call. ALWAYS validate the RETURN of any of the `scanf` functions to ensure the expected number of conversions took place.

Thinking ahead, let's not just use three separate and unrelated buffers. Instead let's declare a `struct` to hold all three, the `icao, ariv & dept` buffers. That way if reading multiple entries into memory, you can simply declare an array of struct and read/parse all values for later user. (the array is left to you)

A simple example here could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXC 1024   /* if you need a constant, define one (or more) */
#define ICAO    6   /* will work for ICAO and time buffer lengths */

typedef struct {
    char icao[ICAO],
        ariv[ICAO],
        dept[ICAO];
} flight_t;

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC];

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {      /* read with fgets */
        flight_t flt = { .icao = "" };      /* declare struct */
        /* separate all value in line into struct, validating return */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%5[^,], %5[^,], %5[^,]", 
                    flt.icao, flt.ariv, flt.dept) == 3)
            /* if sscanf succeeds, output (or use) the values */
            printf ("%s  %s (arrival)  %s (departure)\n",
                    flt.icao, flt.ariv, flt.dept);
    }
}
```

(**note:** how the *field-width* modifier is used before each *character class* conversion specifier to protect the array bounds for each buffer with `"%5[^,], %5[^,], %5[^,]"`. If you have questions about the format-string, just ask.)

Same input file.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/airport_parsetimes <dat/airport_times.txt
KOCH  01:01 (arrival)  01:51 (departure)
KAXX  03:50 (arrival)  05:40 (departure)
KADS  07:40 (arrival)  09:30 (departure)
```

The benefit here, is you now have all values coordinated as a single object, but stored independently so you can access any of the `icao, ariv` or `dept` values as needed while, in the case of an array of struct, still being able to sort the array on any of the struct members while maintaining the association of icao, arrival and departure times.

There are many, many more ways to put the pieces of the puzzle together. The next step would be to dynamically allocate your array of struct and `realloc` as needed to allow you to read an unknown and unlimited number of records (up to the physical memory of your computer). However, the two approaches, (1) parse the buffer with a pointer, or (2) use a formatted input function cover a majority of the cases. All that is left is building upon that foundation as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate solution using a function to look for the first digit.

This will work better than strstr() if you only know that the string you care about starts with a digit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* find_digit(char* string)
{
  while(*string != '\0') {
    char ch = *string;

    if(*string >='0' && *string <= '9') {
      return string;
    }
    string++;

  }
}
int main()
{
  char str[] = "airport, 00:00, 00:00.";

  char* ret = find_digit(str);

  char* remainder = ret + strlen(needle);

  printf("Remainder is: %s\n",remainder);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `strchr()` is easier in that case. The airport name is probably unknown.

Answer (score 0):

`strchr()` will return a *pointer* to the character, meaning it will *move forward* in the string. You can use it as a new string for further operations:

```
char str[] = "airport, 00:00, 00:00.";
char* rem = strchr(str, ','); // rem is now ", 00:00, 00:00."
rem += 2; // rem is now "00:00, 00:00."
rem = strchr(rem, ','); // rem is now ", 00:00, 00:00."
rem += 2; // rem is now "00:00."
*strchr(rem, '.') = 0; // rem is now "00:00" (dot removed)
```

Of course, you should check for `NULL` return, when the character does not exist...

EDIT: Too tempting to give my own implementation for you to see how pointers work in C:

```
char str[] = "airport, 00:00, 00:00.";
char* city = str; // "airport, 00:00, 00:00."
char* departure = strchr(str, ','); // ", 00:00, 00:00."
char* arrival = strchr(departure+1, ','); // ", 00:00."
// Clean up
*departure = 0; // city is now "airport"
departure += 2; // depature is now "00:00, 00:00."
*arrival = 0; // departure is now "00:00"
arrival += 2; // arrival is now "00:00."
*strchr(arrival, '.') = 0;  // arrival is now "00:00"
```

Again, if it's user input, you *must* check for `strchr()` returning `NULL`, because it *will* happen.